# Getting response header in HTTP while request is being sent over HTTPS

Tags: jquery, datatable

I am making an AJAX request using jQuery Datatables, but there is a problem. In the Datatable AJAX request the response headers are in HTTP while I am hitting request over HTTPS.

> Getting ngix 301 response code in response headers with HTTP protocol

The AJAX request is being canceled due to that. You can check the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The problem is because you're making the request from a secure location (ie. `https://...`) and at some point the request is being redirected to a non-secure location (ie. `http://...`). This is not allowed for security reasons. You need to either stop this redirection, or change the redirected URL  to a secure one.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can we change response header url. I have not found any appropriate solution on google to do this

Comment: check the datatables js you included, does they have http or https,